# "Too much recursion" error with basic Haste use

Tags: haskell, haste

I'm trying to put together a little front-end application with `haste`, and I'm running into errors on Firefox. Here's the minimal example of the error:

My Haskell:

```
module Main where

import Haste

main :: IO ()
main = writeLog "Testing..."
```

My HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Experimentascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My compilation output:

```
~/projects/experimentalisp $ hastec Experimentascript.hs
Compiling Main into .
Linking Experimentascript.js
Linking Main
Linking GHC.Tuple
Linking GHC.TopHandler
Linking GHC.IO.Exception
Linking GHC.Types
Linking GHC.Exception
Linking Data.Typeable
Linking Data.Maybe
Linking Haste.Handle
Linking GHC.IO
Linking GHC.Conc.Sync
Linking GHC.Foreign
Linking Foreign.Storable
Linking GHC.Storable
Linking GHC.IO.Buffer
Linking GHC.ForeignPtr
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.Types
Linking Foreign.Marshal.Array
Linking GHC.List
Linking GHC.Err
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.Failure
Linking GHC.Base
Linking GHC.Unicode
Linking GHC.Char
Linking GHC.Show
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv
Linking Foreign.C.Error
Linking GHC.IO.Handle.Types
Linking Foreign.C.Types
Linking GHC.Int
Linking GHC.Integer.Type
Linking GHC.Classes
Linking GHC.Num
Linking Foreign.C.String
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.UTF16
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.UTF32
Linking GHC.IO.Encoding.UTF8
Linking Data.Typeable.Internal
Linking GHC.Fingerprint
Linking GHC.Conc.Signal
Linking Control.Exception.Base
~/projects/experimentalisp $
```

And my Firefox console upon loading the page:

```
22:28:21.635 file:///home/inaimathi/projects/experimentalisp/Experimentascript.js
22:28:18.976 The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. Experimentascript.html
22:28:21.568 too much recursion Experimentascript.js:278
22:28:21.283 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.283 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.286 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.286 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.288 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.289 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.291 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.291 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.293 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.294 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.296 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.296 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.299 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.299 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.301 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.301 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.304 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.304 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.306 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.306 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.309 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.309 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.311 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.311 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.314 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.314 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.316 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.317 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.320 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.320 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.322 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.322 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.325 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.325 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.327 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.327 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.330 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.330 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.332 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.333 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.335 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.335 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.338 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.338 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.340 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.340 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.343 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.343 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.346 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.346 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.348 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.348 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.351 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.351 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.353 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.354 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.356 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.356 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.359 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.359 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.361 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.361 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.364 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.364 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.367 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.367 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.369 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.369 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.372 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.372 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.374 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.375 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.377 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.377 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.380 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.380 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.382 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.382 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.385 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.385 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.388 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.388 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.390 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.390 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.393 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.393 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.395 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.396 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.398 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.398 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.401 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.401 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.403 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.404 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.406 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.406 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.409 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.409 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.411 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.411 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.414 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.414 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.417 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.417 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.419 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.419 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.422 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.422 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.425 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.425 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.427 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.427 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.430 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.430 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.433 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.433 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.435 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.435 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.438 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.438 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.441 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.441 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.443 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.443 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.446 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.446 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.449 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.449 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.451 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.451 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.454 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.454 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.457 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.457 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.459 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.460 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.462 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.462 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.465 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.465 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.468 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.468 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.470 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.470 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.473 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.473 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.476 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.476 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.478 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.478 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.481 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.481 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.484 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.484 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.486 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.487 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.489 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.489 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.492 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.492 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.495 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.495 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.497 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.497 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.500 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.500 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.503 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.503 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.505 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.506 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.508 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.508 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.511 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.511 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.514 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.514 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.516 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.517 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.519 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.519 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.522 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.522 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.525 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.525 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.527 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.527 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.530 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.530 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.533 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.533 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.536 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.536 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.538 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.539 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.541 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.541 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.544 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.544 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
22:28:21.547 "" Experimentascript.js:2111
22:28:21.547 "" Experimentascript.js:2120
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know nothing, but did you see the resolution of https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler/issues/33 ? Also, what version of Haste are you using?

Comment: Wasn't aware of the issue, and don't really see how it's relevant. I'm using `haste` directly out of `cabal install`. `hastec --version` says `0.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was just an issue with the `haste-compiler` version I was running. To resolve it, I had to run

```
cabal update
cabal install haste-compiler
haste-boot
```

in that order. I'm now running `hastec` version `0.4.3`, and no longer getting recursion errors. I did also have to re-install certain haste libraries with

```
haste-inst install <library-name>
```